# how to change ifconfig lo0

Tags: macos

my ifconfig lo0 looks like this:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
inet 192.168.10.11 netmask 0xffffff00
nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

I need to add `inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000`. How can I do it ?

Comment: In Terminal, what's the output of: `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did `lo0` come to have that IP address assigned to it?

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in the Terminal:

```
ifconfig lo0 127.0.0.1/8
```

Or if you want to keep your current (odd) address for the lo0 interface, then add 127.0.0.1 as an additional (alias) address with:

```
ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Don't work for me. I found the solution -> ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.1

Comment: Your setup seems generally broken if you have a 192.168.x.x address on an lo0 interface? Why do you need that?

Comment: I added this for my docker